# Adding CCLayer over a View playing video using MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have created a View which plays video using MPMoviePlayerController. Now I wish to show a CCLayer over/overlapping this View while the video is in action. How to move forward with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//This is where you give path of your video and init it.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video_file_name" ofType:@"mp4/mov"]];
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
NSLog(@"%f", [[CCDirector sharedDirector] view].frame.size.width);
moviePlayer.view.frame = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] view].frame;
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] bringSubviewToFront:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer play];



[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self // the object listening / "observing" to the notification
selector:@selector(playbackComplete:) // method to call when the notification was pushed
name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification // notification the observer should listen to
object:moviePlayer]; // the object that is passed to the method

//[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[MainMenu scene] withColor:ccWHITE]];

}
```

//This is where you define what happens once the playback is complete

```
-(void)playbackComplete:(id)sender {
//    [(MPMoviePlayerController *)sender stop];
//    ((MPMoviePlayerController *)sender).view.hidden=YES;

//    [((MPMoviePlayerController *)sender) removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
[moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
```

//This is where you load another scene(Ex: Image, Animation etc)

```
NSLog(@"Make transition");
CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionSlideInT transitionWithDuration:1.0 scene:[GameLayer scene] ]];

}
```